# Activation context generation failed, dependent assembly, sidebyside, event ID 33

Tags: c++

I am trying to test a DLL which was developed in MSVC 2008, when I try to execute the application that uses the DLL I get an entry in the Application event log:

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program....." Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyTokeb="lfc8b3b9a1e18e3v",type="win32",version="9.0.210122,8" could not be found.  Please use sxtrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

I downloaded and installed the version of the distribution 9.021022, this is from "Programs and Features":

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.21022
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable - 10.0.30319
```

Even though these are installed it still comes up with the same error in the event viewer.

I'm not sure how to use sxtrace.exe

The OS this is running on:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
```

Comment: DebugCRT (and debug variants of runtime libraries in general) is not installed along with MS VC++ redist, it is typically installed along with corresponding toolset.

Comment: @VTT, Is it possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you will need to install MSVC 2008, at least compiler. Maybe you can download debug libraries from somewhere.

Comment: @VTT, I thought this was the issue, a colleague told me otherwise, I can find the libraries on the development system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-compiled project for release, the release dll's were present on the target, the debug version was not required on the target, works without errors now.